# Ошибка при компиляции заголовка в MCVS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, комментарии

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <stdbool.h>

* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *
///                                                                ///
///                            Settings                            ///
///                                                                ///
* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *

    // Визуальные
    const bool Welcome_logo_show   = true; // Выводить приветствие
    const bool Styled_console      = true; // Изменить оформление консоли
    const bool SysInfo_show        = true; // Выводить на экран количество ядер 
    const bool ConsoleFix          = true; // Выводить на экран количество ядер 


#endif
```

Ошибки:
E0040   требуется идентификатор Client  C:\Users\BBCCA\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Settins.hpp   13

E0144   значение типа "bool" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "int **const"  Client  C:\Users\BBCCA\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Settins.hpp   13

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напечатайте текст заголовка и ошибки непосредственно в вопросе вместо предоставления образа экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неправильно написан комментарий.

Многострочные комментарии начинаются с символов `/*` и заканчиваются символами `*/`

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил. Сорри за комментарий